# How to run containerized prometheus, monitor host and sent to grafana

Tags: docker, grafana, prometheus

I have two servers with Ubuntu 18.x.

On one I have installed the official dockerized Grafana.

What I want to do now is installing a dockerized version of Prometheus on the second server and get the host metrics in Grafana.

Do I need a "node_exporter"? Or this doesn't simply work using dockerized version?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it appears that it is not recommended to run both in docker.

So I installed both using package manager and all works good.